# Clean trailing period if present as last non whitespace of dataframe column

Tags: regex, dataframe, data-cleaning

Here's a sample of the data I'm working on(first line are the column names):

```
DENOMINAZIONE;ATC;PRINCIPIO ATTIVO;TITOLARE;AIC    
ABASAGLAR;A10AE04;INSULINA GLARGINE;ELI LILLY NEDERLAND B.V.;043658
ABASRIA;A10AE04;INSULIN GLARGINE;ELI LILLY REGIONAL OPERATIONS GMBH.;043658
 ABECMA;L01;IDECABTAGENE VICLEUCEL;CELGENE EUROPE BV;049604
ABEVMY;L01XC07;BEVACIZUMAB;MYLAN IRE HEALTHCARE LTD ;049452
ABILIFY MAINTENA;N05AX12;ARIPIPRAZOLE;OTSUKA PHARMACEUTICAL EUROPE LTD. ;043143
ABILIFY MAINTENA;N05AX12;ARIPIPRAZOLE;OTSUKA PHARMACEUTICAL EUROPE LTD;043143
```

and I need to eliminate the last '.' so that for example the last two lines become identical. I also need to take into account that sometimes there are leading or trailing whitespaces, possibly more than one.

The CSV file is read into a Pandas.DataFrame comp_df on which I tried the following line:

```
comp_df.TITOLARE.str.replace(r".+\.\s*$", "", regex=True)
```

which does its job of matching one or more non whitespace chars followed by a literal period followed by zero or more spaces until the end of line is reached.

My objective is to lessen the variability of the strings in the TITOLARE series.

The problem is that the lines that match are correctly substituted but the non matching lines are returned as empty.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Since you know exactly what you're doing, why ask a question here ?

Comment: Maybe my English is not clear. I am not understanding why my str.replace line returns either a correct substitution but if it doesn't match returns an empty string. In other words what is the construct to change the series element if it matches but to leave the original content if not? Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately, this `r".+\.\s*$"` matches anything with a dot at the end as well. I can't tell you why this is not good for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not reproduce why the non matching lines are returned as empty, but if you load the example data as csv, set the separator to `;` and only match the dot at the end of the string using between optional whitespace chars using `\s*\.\s*$` you will get the  desired replacement leaving unmatched lines untouched.

Example

```
import pandas as pd

comp_df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", sep=";")
comp_df.TITOLARE = comp_df.TITOLARE.str.replace(r"\s*\.\s*$", "")

print(comp_df)
```

Output

```
      DENOMINAZIONE      ATC        PRINCIPIO ATTIVO                            TITOLARE  AIC    
0         ABASAGLAR  A10AE04       INSULINA GLARGINE             ELI LILLY NEDERLAND B.V    43658
1           ABASRIA  A10AE04        INSULIN GLARGINE  ELI LILLY REGIONAL OPERATIONS GMBH    43658
2            ABECMA      L01  IDECABTAGENE VICLEUCEL                   CELGENE EUROPE BV    49604
3            ABEVMY  L01XC07             BEVACIZUMAB           MYLAN IRE HEALTHCARE LTD     49452
4  ABILIFY MAINTENA  N05AX12            ARIPIPRAZOLE    OTSUKA PHARMACEUTICAL EUROPE LTD    43143
5  ABILIFY MAINTENA  N05AX12            ARIPIPRAZOLE    OTSUKA PHARMACEUTICAL EUROPE LTD    43143
```